# Bi-directional liquid transfer

Tags: hydraulics

I'm attempting to design a system that consists of 4 secondary(ABCW), 1 primary(Film) tank, and a pump. The idea being to Transfer the contents of each secondary tank to the primary one, then back to the source tank before repeating the process for each of the remaining secondary tanks.

The simplest way to do this would be with a 2 way pump, but they seem to be very expensive.

So I've been trying to design around a uni-directional pump, but the simplest layout I've come up with requires 3-4 solenoid valves to route the flow back in the reverse direction.

[image]
(Dark squares represent solenoids, large box is the pump)

Not knowing the first thing about hydraulics, I'm hoping this isn't the optimal design. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Or show me an affordable ≥5L/min bi-directional DC pump?

- Edit: the volume of the tanks is ~1L
- Edit 2: Affordable = Ideally under $100, not over 200

Comment: Let us know what "affordable" means in this context (e.g. 100's USD, 1000's USD)? Please tell us which of the tanks are the secondary tanks and which is the main.

Comment: The right side (ABCW) tanks are secondary, the one marked Film is primary. Affordable is < 100. Each tank's volume is around 1L.

Answer (score 2):

That wouldn't be an uncommon industrial use.  You would need two inlet and two exit valves at the pump to direct flow in or out the way you want.  Plastic 1/4 inch solenoid valves are cheap, manual Ball valves are cheaper.

But for something that small, a simple gear pump would work, and is bi-directional.  Just connect it to a reversing motor.

Comment: Thanks, after looking a bit harder, I found this one https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MF9830S , going to give it a try. If it does the job the  project will be a lot simpler.